# Qt Audio Streaming from IODevice using MAC

Tags: qt, sqlite, streaming, mp3, qmediaplayer

I have a question regarding Qt5.I use a SQlite DB, which contains small mp3 BLOBs.

Now, I stream the audio data, using QMediaPlayer directly from the DB, to play it (using QIODevice).

This works fine with Linux, but when porting to MAC, it does not play the audio.

After doing some google search, I found out, this is because of the different backends, GStreamer vs. QuickTime (supporting streaming, or not).

Question is now, what can I do to make it work? Is it possible, to compile GStreamer statically in my application for Mac? Or do you have a suggestion for virtual file support, so I can use QUrl for QMediaPlayer?

An example would be great, thank you.

Comment: Personally, I would store the mp3s separately and just have a link in the DB to the relevant mp3 file. This will likely make the DB quicker, along with any backups of the DB and mp3s

Comment: Usually I share this opportunity, and when creating a new application, I would do it the way, you suggested. But this DB is distributed to multiple (mobile) platforms, the way it is - so to change it, just for the MAC, would bring up much effort to migrate the DB content every time, the DB content updates (which is pretty often).